# Disable chrome extension conflicting with my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I work on a web site, using jQuery-1.8 , and found out, a certain extension ( on the CEO-s  laptop ) is using jQuery-1.7 as a content script. This content script overwrites my script. Is there a way I can block at least some certain extensions from loading on the chrome tab my web app is using? A meta tag maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Unless the said extension is cooperative (that is it looks for the meta tag, or a specific URL, to disconnect itself), you have no way of disabling it.

You *might* find a way dependent on the extension but you'd need the extension's code to look for it.

In your specific case the problem seems to be that jQuery is overwritten. Can't you simply wrap your code in order to use the specific jQuery you need ?

```
  (function($) {
   // here $ is protected : 
   //   it has the value it had when the page was loaded
  })($);
```

Comment: Well, that is bad news. In this case, I would like to call it a bug : ) I think I will try to tell google about this. It is so annoying.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior by an extension is not really acceptable, you should contact the extension developers to get it fixed.  If they can't be reached, then you should request removal from the Chrome Web Store.